# Resolve city code from user input

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geo

There are a lot of geocode services out there (like http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html for example) where user can write a location (or part of it) and it will be resolved to real existing location.

There is also a lot of info provided with the search result (like country ISO code, coordinates, etc..), but none of the services seem to provide country and city code.

What I mean is a code used to phone to certain are. For example Country code for Germany will be 49 and for city of Dusseldorf will be 211.

Is there any service, where I can get this info from the user input. Or is there any way to combine the two. For example I get city name from google geocode service and the try it on some city codes database. If yes, can anyone please provide me with links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for instance Yahoo's [GeoPlanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/). For more elaboration on services to solve your problem you might want to check out [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/603/is-a-country-state-city-database-available) answer on [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com), which seems to cover the kind of service you need.

Comment: GeoPlanet is no longer available in the URL.